# Plot 3 dimensional unequal length of data

Tags: gnuplot

I am new in gnuplot so excuse me if it looks simple. I have a data file like below and I want to draw a diagram like this:

[image]

```
t       x = 0.00        0.20        0.40        0.60        0.80        1.00
0.00    0.000000    0.640000    0.960000    0.960000    0.640000    0.000000
0.02    0.000000    0.480000    0.800000    0.800000    0.480000    0.000000
0.04    0.000000    0.400000    0.640000    0.640000    0.400000    0.000000
0.06    0.000000    0.320000    0.520000    0.520000    0.320000    0.000000
0.08    0.000000    0.260000    0.420000    0.420000    0.260000    0.000000
0.10    0.000000    0.210000    0.340000    0.340000    0.210000    0.000000
0.12    0.000000    0.170000    0.275000    0.275000    0.170000    0.000000
0.14    0.000000    0.137500    0.222500    0.222500    0.137500    0.000000
0.16    0.000000    0.111250    0.180000    0.180000    0.111250    0.000000
0.18    0.000000    0.090000    0.145625    0.145625    0.090000    0.000000
0.20    0.000000    0.072813    0.117813    0.117813    0.072813    0.000000
```

GNU octave equivalent command is something like this:

```
mesh(tplot,xplot,ttplot);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as with many things, it is simple if you know how. This is straighforward to plot if you remove the `x =` and the `t` from the data file, e.g.:

```
0           0.00        0.20        0.40        0.60        0.80        1.00
0.00    0.000000    0.640000    0.960000    0.960000    0.640000    0.000000
0.02    0.000000    0.480000    0.800000    0.800000    0.480000    0.000000
0.04    0.000000    0.400000    0.640000    0.640000    0.400000    0.000000
0.06    0.000000    0.320000    0.520000    0.520000    0.320000    0.000000
0.08    0.000000    0.260000    0.420000    0.420000    0.260000    0.000000
0.10    0.000000    0.210000    0.340000    0.340000    0.210000    0.000000
0.12    0.000000    0.170000    0.275000    0.275000    0.170000    0.000000
0.14    0.000000    0.137500    0.222500    0.222500    0.137500    0.000000
0.16    0.000000    0.111250    0.180000    0.180000    0.111250    0.000000
0.18    0.000000    0.090000    0.145625    0.145625    0.090000    0.000000
0.20    0.000000    0.072813    0.117813    0.117813    0.072813    0.000000
```

Then the data can be interpreted as a "non-uniform" matrix, although it is uniform. This is useful as it reads the first row and first column correctly. See `help matrix` and `help matrix nonuniform` for more. For example:

```
echo 'splot "data" nonuniform matrix with lines' | gnuplot --persist
```

Gives me:

[image: Plot of data matrix]

To make it similar to the output produced by the GNU Octave `mesh` command, do something like this:

```
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "t"
set zlabel "u"
set view 20,210
set border 4095 lw 2
set hidden3d
set xyplane 0
set autoscale fix
set nokey
set notics
splot "data" nonuniform matrix lt -1 lw 2 with lines
```

Which results in:

[image: Plot that is more similar to the original]

Comment: Thank you Thor, Nice answer.